# What size does a transaction have?

Tags: transactions, transaction-weight

Transaction size should be the same right? I get that there were updates to the btc network that changes the size of transactions. But if you just look at transactions since the last updates, how big in size are those?

I'm asking because I saw blocks with 3k+ transactions and was wondering how much space they actually take. I was under the impression that bitcoin blocks are 1MB, but it seems that that's not really true, so I thought at least transactions should be more or less the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a transaction depends on the numbers of inputs and outputs it contains.

Although many transactions might have one input and two outputs, some transactions can have hundreds of inputs and/or hundreds of outputs.

It is also affected by the type of each output (P2PKH, Segwit, etc).

---

- [Block sizes at blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks?s=id(desc)#f=id,time,transaction_count,fee,fee_usd,size)
- [Transaction sizes at blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?)

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense... So the guy asking about average transaction size actually asked the right question. Although, it didn't consider network upgrades for all i care (his question is also 9 years old, so that's understandable).